# Escaping the result of a subquery in sql insert statements for pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, mariadb

I'm importing a csv on MariaDB using python & pandas,the isert statements need a couple of subqueries, here is the code:

```py
empdata = pd.read_csv(
    "static/files/testfile.csv",
    index_col=False, delimiter=";", on_bad_lines="skip"
)


if conn.is_connected():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select database();")
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    # print (record)
    print("You're connected to database: ", record)
    # loop through the data frame
    for i, row in empdata.iterrows():
        # print(row)
        # here %S means string values
        sql = "INSERT INTO PRODOTTI (PROD_ATTIVO,EAN13,prod_nome,Prezzo,CAT_IVA_idCAT_IVA,Costo,Quantita,Fornitori_idFornitori,Data_ins) \
                VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,(select idCAT_IVA from CAT_IVA where CAT_IVA_aliquota = %s),%s,%s,(select idFornitori from Fornitori where Fornitori_nome = %s),%s)"
```

and all works fine until one of the answer of a subuery contains a space than I got this error:

(1, '3649833526', 'Example product', 15.9, 0.22, '8.94', '2', **'example dealer',** '2021/01/02')
Error while inserting in DB 1048 (23000): Column 'Fornitori_idFornitori' cannot be null

It seems to me that the subqueries search just for **'example'** and not for **'example dealer'** so it get a NULL answer, and I haven't found a way to escape this field and avoid this behaviour.

Some one knows how to solve this issue?

Thank you.

I've tried different csv encoding and escaping in the query but without result.

Comment: Please edit your question to correct typos.  The code provided is not syntactically valid (it seems the beginning of the lines are missing?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you defined Fornitori_idFornitori as `NOT NULL` you need to provide a value for the column, as 0 isn't part if an auto_increment you can use it or -1

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO PRODOTTI (PROD_ATTIVO,EAN13,prod_nome,Prezzo,CAT_IVA_idCAT_IVA,Costo,Quantita,Fornitori_idFornitori,Data_ins) \
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,COALESCE((select idCAT_IVA from CAT_IVA where CAT_IVA_aliquota = %s),0),%s,%s,COALESCE((select idFornitori from Fornitori where Fornitori_nome = REPLACE(%s, ' ','')),0),%s)"
```

Comment: I suppose that the value was provided by the subquery: (select idFornitori from Fornitori where Fornitori_nome = %s) whic is not null is it pass 'example dealer', but I suppose it only pass 'example'. To be clear the "Fornitori_nome " provided in the CSV is always present in the Fornitori table.

Comment: you have a select that returns NULLl as the value is not present, but Fornitori_idFornitori  can't be NULL, so the coalesce will give you  a correct code that will be inserted. You should of course check each value if it returns an id and only insert when, yu receive an id, but with my approach you can seach for 0 in Fornitori_idFornitori  and then find the rows easioly in your csv

Comment: I was not clear, in table " Fornitori" the  idFornitori related to  Fornitori_nome = 'example dealer' is present, the query doesn't find it becouse of the space in the name so it returns null, and I'm unable to instruct pandas to ignore the space.

Comment: i edited my answer, if ou only want to get rid of the spaces in  the tet use a simple replace

Comment: Well, it worked, now I had to solve some other strange behaviour. Thank you. :) I've learned coalesce and replace :)